# Can 1 namespace span across multiple EKS clusters?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to understand the relation between namespaces and clusters in EKS. Can 1 namespace span across multiple EKS clusters? Is that possible?

Comment: The Kubernetes descendant OpenShift calls this "project" rather than "namespace" which I think makes it much more clear how to approach it and what it is good for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Kubernetes supports multiple virtual clusters backed by the same physical cluster. These virtual clusters are called namespaces.

[Kubernetes concepts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/)

So, no, a namespace can not span across multiple Kubernetes clusters. You can have namespaces with the same name in multiple clusters. But those would be different objects as a namespace is defined on the cluster level.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thanks!